# Why i am getting not index error with this variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am making an analysis of a FIFA 22 soccer players, and i want to make a graph with the faster players, but when i make a variable it gives that error.

```
Analise01 = df[["sofifa_id", "short_name", "movement_sprint_speed"]]

dados01 = Analise01.groupby( by = ["sofifa_id"]).sum().reset_index()[["sofifa_id", 
"short_name", "movement_sprint_speed"]].sort_values("movement_sprint_speed", ascending = 
False)
dados01.head(5)
```

Then when I play this cell, it gives the error: "not in index"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is when you do `.groupby()` and `.sum()`, you get back a datframe that only has the `id` as the index and the `speed` column (since you can't sum a string/`'name'` column).

So you'd need to either a) merge on the sum values to the `id`, or include the `'name'` in the groupby, so you don't lose that column.

However, why are you using `.sum()` here? I'm assuming there aren't multiple rows of a player with speeds (as I'm familar with EA sports, each player has it's own speed attribute, summing doesn't make sense here to me.) Are you just trying to sort to get the fastest?

But this will get your code to work:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'sofifa_id': 1, 'short_name': 'foo', 'movement_sprint_speed': 95},
        {'sofifa_id': 1, 'short_name': 'foo', 'movement_sprint_speed': 95},
        {'sofifa_id': 2, 'short_name': 'foo', 'movement_sprint_speed': 82},
        {'sofifa_id': 5, 'short_name': 'foo', 'movement_sprint_speed': 83}]

analise01 = pd.DataFrame(data)




dados01 = analise01.groupby( by = ["sofifa_id"]).sum().reset_index()
dados01 = dados01.merge(analise01.drop("movement_sprint_speed", axis=1), how='left', on=['sofifa_id']).drop_duplicates()
dados01 = dados01.sort_values("movement_sprint_speed", ascending = False).reset_index(drop=True)
dados01.head(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your problem with the following toy example (which worked the way you wanted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'name', 'speed'])

df = df.append({'id': 1, 'name': 'foo', 'speed': 5}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'id': 1, 'name': 'foo', 'speed': 5}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'id': 2, 'name': 'foo', 'speed': 2}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'id': 3, 'name': 'foo', 'speed': 3}, ignore_index=True)


dados01 = df.groupby( by = ["id"]).sum().reset_index()[["id", 
"name", "speed"]].sort_values("speed", ascending = 
False)



id  name    speed
0   1   foofoo  10
2   3   foo 3
1   2   foo 2
```

But when I used your first line:

```
df2 = df[['id', 'name', 'speed']]

I got the same error:

dados01 = df2.groupby( by = ["id"]).sum().reset_index()[["id", 
"name", "speed"]].sort_values("speed", ascending = 
False)

KeyError: "['name'] not in index"
```

I can't tell you exactly why this is the case here, but putting a `.copy()` at the end of your first line worked for me.

So I just did

```
df2 = df[['id', 'name', 'speed']].copy()
```

and the result was the same as using the original df

```
id  name    speed
0   1   foofoo  10
2   3   foo 3
1   2   foo 2
```

Weird pandas error!

You also may want to make the id/name columns as the index so you don't get the summed value of 'name' in the output too like I did. Hope this helps!